# How do I skip a comparison between two of the same arrays index?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, data-structures

I'm doing this really simple codewars kata below is the problem:

> An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or
>   non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string
>   that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is
>   an isogram. Ignore letter case.

```
function isIsogram(str){
  var letter = str.toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    if(letter.indexOf(letter[i].toLowerCase()) > -1){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; 
}
```

My solution always returns false because my array within indexOf compares every letter within my string. The solution is supposed to compare the array with itself and return true if there are no repeating letters. But unfortunately for me when comparing the array with itself it is going to compare each letter within the array on itself so basically even if there is only one letter of that char in the array, because again it is comparing with itself, it is going to return a false statement.

This problem is killing me.

Comment: In your if statement, could you add something like `&& letter.indexOf(letter[i].toLowerCase()) !== i` ?

Comment: You are better off sorting the string first then walking it and comparing the current letter with the next one. Your algorithm is considered slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the [Array#lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) (it searches from the end) is the same as current index. If not, it's not unique:

```js
function isIsogram(str){
  var letter = str.toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    if(letter.lastIndexOf(letter[i]) !== i){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; 
}

console.log(isIsogram('subdermatoglyphic'));
console.log(isIsogram('rare'));
```

A better solution is to compare the number of unique characters using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) vs. the number of characters in the original string:

```js
const isIsogram = (str) => new Set(str.toLowerCase()).size === str.length;

console.log(isIsogram('subdermatoglyphic'));
console.log(isIsogram('rare'));
```

Comment: Theres no difference between using indexOf and lastIndexOf except one being faster.

Comment: The difference is in the usage: You can use `lastIndexOf()`, and compare it to the current index, or `indexOf()` with a start position, and check if the result is -1.

Comment: I just changed my `> -1` into `!== i` and that basically solved my problem. This makes so much sense because when getting the index of that letter if it is NOT equal to its index,even though it does, it returns false! I like the logic! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome :) If you use `indexOf()` with this logic, and without a start index, it will only fail when reaching the 2nd appearance of the letter. This is why I've used `lastIndexOf()`.

Answer (score 1):

More simple:

```
check = str => new Set( str.toLowerCase() ).size === str.length;
```

Or if you wanna fix your code, use two loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
  for(var j = i+1; j < letter.length; j++){
    if(letter[i] === letter[j]) return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isIsogram(str){
  var letter = str.toLowerCase().split("");

  for(var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    for (var y = i + 1; y < letter.length; y++) {
         if (letter[i] === letter[y])
            return false;
    }
  }
  return true; 
}
```

extra efficiency by not duplicating comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient solution using the approach proposed by @rafael: reorder the word alphabetically and incrementally compare each letter to the next.  If there's a match, immediately return false.

```
function isIsogram(word) {
    word = word.split('').sort().join('').toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === word[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: The most efficient solution would be using a `Set` or an object to remember the previously seen letters (but really, this isn't worth optimizing for such small data).